# How can I find the correlation between 3 field patterns around 3 antennae

Tags: probability, statistics

I have collected experimental data about a WiFi antenna by measuring the field strength at points around 3 of these antennae. I now have a sampled the strength in dBm every 0.5m along a radius of 6.5m around the antenna at 45 degree intervals.

I now want to see how much the field pattern varies around the antenna as if they are correlated I will be able to use the received signal strength and rotation of the antenna (to be placed on top of robots) for better localisation as the distance prediction based on the received signal strength would be more accurate regardless of the antenna being used.

Can anyone suggest a method or model that would suit my requirement?

Comment: A tough problem, I think. If your robots are moving indoors or near buildings, there will be multipath propagation (reflected signals from such surfaces and other scatterers), and cancelling those is a tall order. Statiscal tools will become necessary. Beamforming?

Comment: I'm assuming perfect outdoor open conditions to begin with. I'm basically just looking to figure out if the 3 3D polar plots I have are correlated with some maths instead of visual inspection.